# i need a server who support Rails and Java

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services

i need a server who support ruby on rails and java

someone know about server who support those 2 programing languages?

Comment: What "server"? Do you need dedicated hosting for RoR and.. "java". What do you mean by Java exactly? Java Servlets? JDBC? Java Beans? Struts? Server Pages?

Comment: Get a dedicated server plan. Install all the software needed for Java and Ruby (and Rails). Then run two servers Mongrel and Tomcat. I guess Glassfish supports both ROR and Java. You may check Glassfish 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use JRuby for Ruby on Rails. There are some ways that you can convert your RoR application into a war file to deploy in a Java Application Server, like Tomcat. So, any Java Application Server can support both java and RoR applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Deploying Ruby on Rails is easy](http://rubyonrails.org/deploy) page on the [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org).